# Bidirectional relationship in Hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I am creating an application with Hibernate Search. I noticed that all the examples used bi-directional relationships. I read the following:

> When @IndexedEmbedded points to an entity, the association has to be
>   directional and the other side has to be annotated @ContainedIn (as
>   seen in the previous example). If not, Hibernate Search has no way to
>   update the root index when the associated entity is updated (in our
>   example, a Place index document has to be updated when the associated
>   Address instance is updated).

[Hibernate Search chapter 4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html/search-mapping.html)

Isn't this a bad thing if I consider the JPA part of my application? Is it normal that all objects should now where they are used/what they have? Is it anyone who have some experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically giving an opinion on your question if it is a bad thing to have your object "know where they are used":

You are not introducing a dependency to the business logic layer; that would indeed be fishy but it's not the case.
In this case you are making an existing link more explicit: these are entities which have a relation in data terms, and it's actually better to highlight this relation so that anyone examining entity A will be immediately aware of the relation to entity B: this relation would otherwise be hidden but still existing on the physical layer, and for someone working on the mapping it's better to keep that in mind.

It has no performance drawbacks whatsoever, no drawbacks on the schema, and has the practical benefit that it might be useful to your business logic avoiding the need to maintain additional queries.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't this a bad thing if I consider the JPA part of my application?
>   Is it normal that all objects should now where they are used/what they
>   have? Is it anyone who have some experience with this?

Not a bad thing at all. In fact it is quite common that you have bidirectional associations, because often you need to navigate both ways in the entity graph depending on the use case. Also note, that due to lazy loading it is often not a performance or memory problem to have bidirectional associations.

That said, if you really don't need and want bidirectional associations you are free to use unidirectional ones. However, in this case you need to be careful on using *@IndexedEmbedded* for the reason described in the Hibernate Search documentation.